# HMC SHA1 hash - Java producing different hash output than C#

Tags: java, c#, cryptography, sha1, hmac

This is a follow up to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7175067/hmc-sha1-hash-c-sharp-producing-different-hash-output-than-ruby) question, but I'm trying to port C# code to Java instead of Ruby code to C#, as was the case in the related question.  I am trying to verify the encrypted [signature](http://docs.recurly.com/recurlyjs/signatures) returned from the Recurly.js api is valid.  Unfortunately, Recurly does not have a Java library to assist with the validation, so I must implement the signature validation myself.

Per the related question above ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7175067/hmc-sha1-hash-c-sharp-producing-different-hash-output-than-ruby)), the following C# code can produce the hash needed to validate the signature returned from Recurly:

```
var privateKey = Configuration.RecurlySection.Current.PrivateKey;
var hashedKey = SHA1.Create().ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(privateKey));
var hmac = new HMACSHA1(hashedKey);
var hash = hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dataToProtect));
return BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
```

Recurly provides the following example data on their [signature](http://docs.recurly.com/recurlyjs/signatures) documentation page:

> **unencrypted verification message**: 
>   [1312701386,transactioncreate,[account_code:ABC,amount_in_cents:5000,currency:USD]]
>
> **private key**:
>   0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF
>
> **resulting signature**:
>   0f5630424b32402ec03800e977cd7a8b13dbd153-1312701386

Here is my Java implementation:

```
String unencryptedMessage = "[1312701386,transactioncreate,[account_code:ABC,amount_in_cents:5000,currency:USD]]";
String privateKey = "0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF";
String encryptedMessage = getHMACSHA1(unencryptedMessage, getSHA1(privateKey));

private static byte[] getSHA1(String source) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException{
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
    byte[] bytes = md.digest(source.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    return bytes;
}

private static String getHMACSHA1(String baseString, byte[] keyBytes) throws GeneralSecurityException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "HmacSHA1");
    Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
    mac.init(secretKey);
    byte[] bytes = baseString.getBytes("ASCII");
    return Hex.encodeHexString(mac.doFinal(bytes));
}
```

However, when I print out the encryptedMessage variable, it does not match the message portion of the example signature.  Specifically, I get a value of "c8a9188dcf85d1378976729e50f1de5093fabb78" instead of "0f5630424b32402ec03800e977cd7a8b13dbd153".

**Update**

Per @M.Babcock, I reran the C# code with the example data, and it returned the same output as the Java code.  So it appears my hashing approach is correct, but I am passing in the wrong data (unencryptedMessage).  Sigh. I will update this post if/when I can determine what the correct data to encrypt is- as the "unencrypted verification message" provided in the Recurly documentation appears to be missing something.

**Update 2**

The error turned out to be the "unencrypted verification message" data/format.  The message in the example data does not actually encrypt to the example signature provided- so perhaps outdated documentation? At any rate, I have confirmed the Java implementation will work for real-world data. Thanks to all.

Comment: Have you verified that you are feeding the same values to the hash functions in both languages? If the inputs differ then so will the outputs.

Comment: Further to @M.Babcock's point, I'd suggest you change the string and key to something simple, like "Hello" and "World". It *looks* like you've got identical values in both cases, but it's much easier to verify that with simple strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is in your .NET code. Does `Configuration.RecurlySection.Current.PrivateKey` return a string? Is that value the key you expect?

Using the following code, .NET and Java return identical results.

**.NET Code**

```
string message = "[1312701386,transactioncreate,[account_code:ABC,amount_in_cents:5000,currency:USD]]";
string privateKey = "0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF";

var hashedKey = SHA1.Create().ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(privateKey));
var hmac = new HMACSHA1(hashedKey);
var hash = hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message));

Console.WriteLine("  Message: {0}", message);
Console.WriteLine("      Key: {0}\n", privateKey);
Console.WriteLine("Key bytes: {0}", BitConverter.ToString(hashedKey).Replace("-", "").ToLower());
Console.WriteLine("   Result: {0}", BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", "").ToLower());
```

**Result:**

```
  Message: [1312701386,transactioncreate,[account_code:ABC,amount_in_cents:5000,currency:USD]]
      Key: 0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF

Key bytes: 4d857d2408b00c3dd17f0c4ffcf15b97f1049867
   Result: c8a9188dcf85d1378976729e50f1de5093fabb78
```

**Java**

```
String message = "[1312701386,transactioncreate,[account_code:ABC,amount_in_cents:5000,currency:USD]]";
String privateKey = "0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF";

MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
byte[] keyBytes = md.digest(privateKey.getBytes("UTF-8"));

SecretKey sk = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "HmacSHA1");
Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
mac.init(sk);
byte[] result = mac.doFinal(message.getBytes("ASCII"));

System.out.println("  Message: " + message);
System.out.println("      Key: " + privateKey + "\n");
System.out.println("Key Bytes: " + toHex(keyBytes));
System.out.println("  Results: " + toHex(result));
```

**Result:**

```
  Message: [1312701386,transactioncreate,[account_code:ABC,amount_in_cents:5000,currency:USD]]
      Key: 0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF

Key Bytes: 4d857d2408b00c3dd17f0c4ffcf15b97f1049867
  Results: c8a9188dcf85d1378976729e50f1de5093fabb78
```

Comment: This is true. I will have to investigate what is returned from Configuration.RecurlySection.Current.PrivateKey, as I assumed it was a string of the private key.

Comment: It turns out the key is in fact in string format. The real culprit turned out to be the unencryptedMessage format. See Update 2 in my question.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the default encoding of the values you're working on may be different. As they do not have it specified, they will use the default encoding value of the string based on the platform you're working on.

I did a quick search to verify if this was true and it was still inconclusive, but it made me think that strings in .NET default to UTF-16 encoding, while Java defaults to UTF-8. (Can someone confirm this?)

If such's the case, then your `GetBytes` method with UTF-8 encoding is already producing a different output for each case.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/AuthJavaSampleHMACSignature.html) sample code, it looks like Java expects you to have not already SHA1'd your key before creating a SecretKeySpec. Have you tried that?

Comment: I have tried just passing in the unencrypted key (not SHA1'd), and then getting the bytes from that to pass into the SecretKeySpec, but to no avail. It returns a different hash, but still not the right one.